# Convert Number into Date format in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have number column in oracle database which stores a timestamp. I want to convert this into a `DATE` and I have no clue on how to do it.

Below is what I am looking for, please suggest.

The value `1465484486246` should be converted to `2016/06/09 15:01:26,246 GMT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NUMTODSINTERVAL` along with `to_date` to achieve what you want:

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1970/01/01 00:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(col / 1000,'SECOND'),
        'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Here I assume that your timestamp column is called `col`.  The timestamp `1465484486246` you gave us is in milliseconds, which is why I used `col / 1000` in `NUMTODSINTERVAL`.

Comment: I am getting result as "09-JUN-16", rest of the part is missing in result set.

Comment: Now i am getting ORA-01843: not a valid month error while executing sql.